# What is a good server side validation library for .net?

Tags: asp.net, validation, server-side

I am trying to find a validation library to validate user input on the server side

Basically, I would like to avoid the following code appearing 15-20 times per page :

```
If Not String.IsNullorEmpty(txtDate.text) Then
    StrMsg.appendline("Please enter Date")
ElseIf Not IsDate(txtDate.text) Then
    StrMsg.appendline("Date must be numeric")
End If
```

I want to do something like this :

```
StrMsg.AppendLine(ValidateField(txtDate, SQLDataType.Date, Required))
```

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in Validation controls

[User Input Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx)

[Validation controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx)

After you have configured validation controls, all you have to do is check

```
Page.IsValid
```

Comment: If I have a page with 20 controls to validate, I have to put 20 validators on the page? I was hoping for a programmatic solution.

Comment: Yes, you put 20 validators on the page. Alternatively, if there is a pattern, you can create a user control containing a Label, a TextBox, and a validator, and just use 20 instances of that.

Comment: yea but you dont have duplicate your validation logic for a page. ASP.NET MVC has a better input validation mechanism